# How to set php array index as array value...?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have this array from a query.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
            [first_name] => Diyaa
            [profile_pic] => profile/user5.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 8
            [first_name] => Raj
            [profile_pic] => profile/user8.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [first_name] => Vanathi
            [profile_pic] => profile/user10.jpg
        )
)
```

I need to set **array index** as like **array value** (`user_id`) as given below:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 5
            [first_name] => Diyaa
            [profile_pic] => profile/user5.png
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 8
            [first_name] => Raj
            [profile_pic] => profile/user8.jpg
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [first_name] => Vanathi
            [profile_pic] => profile/user10.jpg
        )
)
```

**Note:** `user_id` is an unique value, it won't repeat again. No need to worry about index value.

How to convert and get that array as specified index value..?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I think he wants what laravel calls [`keyBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keyby)

Comment: @apokryfos ah I see - removed comment :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this code, here I do some extra work. Refer to **[AbraCadaver's clever answer `$result = array_column($array, null, 'user_id');`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44183974/6521116)**.

```
array_combine(array_column($array, 'user_id'), $array);
```

Comment: Clever.  I always ended up using a loop.  Nice combo!

Comment: Out of curiosity - I don't see it in the documentation - but is your understanding that `array_column` preserves order? That would be necessary for this to work.

Comment: @yes, I've tryed it. I  think here php may be use the iterator to get it.

Comment: Why array_combine()?  The third parameter to array_column() does just this.

Comment: @AbraCadaver great way. I've never notice it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what `array_column()` is for:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'user_id');
```

> array_column() returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. **Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array.**
>
> **column_key**
>
> The column of values to return. This value may be an integer key of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for an associative array or property name. **It may also be NULL to return complete arrays or objects (this is useful together with index_key to reindex the array).**

Comment: using this pretty function daily, first time to try to pass the second parameter as null :)

Answer (score 0):

Both structures are unnecessarily complex and redundant.  Why not

```
$foo = array(5 =>
          array('first_name' => 'Diyaa',
                'profile_pic' => 'profile/user5.png'),
             8 =>
          array('first_name' => 'Raj',
                'profile_pic' => 'profile/user8.png'),
          ...
            );
```

Then access it via `$foo[$user_id]`, which will give you a 2-element associative array such as

```
          array('first_name' => 'Raj',
                'profile_pic' => 'profile/user8.png'),
```

For changing a profile_pic:

```
$foo[$user_id]['profile_pic'] = $new_pic;
```